# Thymeleaf не видит файл

Tags: java, spring

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during parsing(template: "class path resource
>   [templates/addProduct.jsp]")

Возникает, когда я попадаю на контроллер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Что интересно, он работал, я ни со страницей, ни с контроллером ничего не делал, а он работать перестал.
Папка расположения VIEW стоит дефолтная - `resources/templates/`, установлен только `suffix=.jsp`.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: _An error happened during parsing_ - у Вас что-то не так со страницей.